# Какие эпитеты можно использовать со словом «трафик»?

Tags: лексика, стилистика, заимствования, лексическая-сочетаемость, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Трафик: высокий, низкий, интенсивный, слабый, большой, маленький.
Какие эпитеты использовать?

Слово *трафик* широко используется в двух значениях: **трафик данных** (интернет-трафик, телефонный трафик) и **дорожный трафик**. В первом случае кажется привычным эпитет *высокий*: высокий интернет-трафик, высокий трафик в мобильных сетях и т. п.
А можно ли назвать *высоким* дорожный трафик?

*Ленинградское шоссе в Москве отличается **высоким автомобильным трафиком***.

Какие еще эпитеты можно использовать с этим словом в разных ситуациях употребления?
Можно ли сказать *маленький трафик, слабый трафик* — в отношении дорожной обстановки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Высокий/маленький/слабый трафик*" (в плане дорожного движения) мне режет слух.

В таких случаях говорят "*перегруженный трафик*" или "*интенсивный трафик/движение*". Ну или "*на дорогах час пик*".
"*Умеренный трафик*" нормально звучит.

Comment: Вот и мне режет. Спасибо!

Comment: Иногда  "слабый" может звучать нормально: *Что-то на дорогах сейчас слабый трафик, обычно он гораздо интенсивнее* (здесь и "выше" звучит). Иногда может звучать "активный трафик". Вывод: контекст может сглаживать сочетаемость.

Comment: Но при этом с антонимом _сильный_ вообще не звучит. _В Москве сегодня слабый трафик._ И "низкий" тоже не подходит. _По понедельникам в Подмосковье низкий дорожный трафик._

Comment: Да, "сильный" вряд ли спасёт контекст. И наверно, "низкий" тоже. И "слабый" в этом примере не звучит. Слово "что-то" как бы сглаживает: *Что-то в Москве сегодня слабый трафик.* Это связано с разговорным стилем.

Comment: @oleedd Ваши слова в ответе: *В таких случаях говорят "перегруженный трафик" или "интенсивный трафик/движение"*. **Где-то** нужно подправить: ***интенсивный движение*** быть не должно.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Понимаю, что не идеально. Но это равносильно "*интенсивный трафик или движение*". Знак "/" — или.

Answer (score -1):

Так как эпитет – это художественное определение, придающее выражению образность и эмоциональность, мне кажется, этот термин в данном случае неуместен. Если же необходим именно эпитет, можно предложить следующие варианты: чудный, несчастный, подозрительный и тому подобные. )

Comment: Слово "_эпитет_" широко используется за пределами литературоведения. В обычной речи "эпитетом" часто называют определение, которое передает  признак или состояние конкретного объекта в определенный момент. "_Синяя шапка_": синяя не эпитет, потому что это свойство шапки. "_Интенсивное движение_": интенсивное - эпитет, потому что характеризует состояние движения в конкретный момент. Отдельно хочу заметить, что ваш ответ на мой вопрос абсолютно бесполезен: я интересовалась лексической сочетаемостью слов, а не значением слова "эпитет".

Comment: Такое принято писать в комментариях под вопросом (потому что это не ответ на вопрос) либо добавлять к непосредственно ответу.